# Change UIButton tint color while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom table view header that becomes blurred when the user scrolls down. Id like to change the tint color of one of the navigation bar items items (its not a nav bar button item, just a UIButton). I have been using the tableviews contentOffset.y property to animate buttons, and blur the background image view. I need to do this to the tint color as well but I can figure out how.

For example this is code to shrink the profile pic and the hide some views using the alpha property

```
func movingUp(offset: CGFloat) {
    if infoView.alpha >= 0 {
        let alphaOffset = (offset - 133)/105.0
        infoView.alpha = alphaOffset*1.2
        profilePic.alpha = alphaOffset
    }

    if profileWidth.constant >= 45 {
        profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = (((offset - 133)/105.0) * 90)/2
        profileHeight.constant = ((offset - 133)/105.0) * 90
        profileWidth.constant = ((offset - 133)/105.0) * 90
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to set the colour but you need to have two extremes of the colour. What should the colour be at the top of the table view and at the bottom of the table view? Unless you want it to change randomly then you need a "start" and "end" colour that you want it to change between.

Comment: At the top the color is white, at the bottom the color is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer that will help you here... http://www.oliverfoggin.com/controlling-animations-with-a-uiscrollview/

The idea is that you can move between two extreme values by using the current content offset and using it as a percentage based on the maximum offset.

In your case, it's easy as the colour is a simple inverse function of the percentage.

i.e.

```
let color = UIColor(white: 1.0 - percentage, alpha: 1.0)
```

When the percentage is 0.0 (i.e. top of the table) then the white value is 1.0 = white.

When the percentage is 1.0 (i.e. bottom of the table) then the white value is 0.0 = black.

I just realised that my post is in Objective-C. It should be very easy to convert to Swift as it just uses simple math functions. If you'd like me to convert it let me know and I'll put it here.

Comment: thats great! what if the color was UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 102/255, blue: 102/255, alpha: 1)

Comment: @JeremySh you would need a minimum and maximum. You can see in my post I have set a minimum and maximum hue. Also, if you're using the same number for each value (like 102/255 here) then just use the `UIColor(white...)` method instead of the `red:green:blue:` method.